# Is it possible to print a next line in a code?

Tags: python, string, stack

Is it possible to make a method, which prints a next line of a code?

```
def print_next_line():
    sth

import fxx

print 'XXX'
print_next_line()
file.split('/')
....

>>> 'XXX'
>>> 'file.split('/')'
```

I was thinking that It could be somewhere in the stack, but I'm not sure because it is next, not previous line.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @Alik It is for debugging purposes.

Comment: could you please elaborate?

Comment: @Alik There was a lot of situations when I needed this. For example when I needed to know which line of code takes too much time or where is the script freezing.

Comment: well, there are a lot of good profilers you could use to determine which lines of code take too much time.

Answer (score 2):

Straight approach. I use [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html) module to determine file and line where `print_next_line` was called. Later I read the file to find next string. You might want to  add some error handling here (what if there is no next line in a file? and so on)

```
def print_next_line():
    def get_line(f, lineno):
        with open(f) as fp:
            lines = fp.readlines()
            return lines[lineno-1]

    import inspect
    callerframerecord = inspect.stack()[1]
    frame = callerframerecord[0]
    info = inspect.getframeinfo(frame)
    line_ = info.lineno
    file_ = info.filename
    print get_line(file_, line_ + 1)

print 'XXX'
a = 1
print_next_line()
b = a*2
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need is a [profiling tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_%28computer_programming%29) or just a [debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger).

Answer (score 1):

Use Python's [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/inspect.html) module:

```
import inspect

def print_next_line():
    lineno = inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_lineno
    with open(__file__) as f:
        print(f.readlines()[lineno].rstrip())
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you could `open()` your .py file and iterate to find specific line, then print it.